# Validation rule in Oracle Sales Cloud

Tags: oracle, validationrule

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but I'm writing this validation rule in Oracle Sales Cloud 11 on the account object (field : Address Line 1), and it always returns false even if true, I don't get it. I've tried several formulations, but the issue remains, thanks a lot for your help.

```
if (PrimaryAddressLine1 == null) {
  return false
}
else {
  return true
}
```

Comment: try to add `:` before PrimaryAddressLine1 , maybe , it can help

Comment: Thanks for your reply Laith. Unfortunately it didn't work, an error appeared : unexpected token.

Comment: Similar behavior is seen for me too. But if your end result was to make the Address Line 1 mandatory/required; then you can try making that from Manage Address Formats in Setup and Maintenance

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the validation at object level, can you place the required/mandatory requirement by configuring in Manage Address Formats and handle it there. Making Address Line 1 required at this Level will make it required across objects where OOTB Address Section is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

> if (!PrimaryAddressLine1) {
>       return false } else {
>       return true }

Comment: If you can give more details on what you are working on so that we can properly help you.Thus, I can give a more correct answer.